# Mysql query(same) returns different result order with different result set

Tags: mysql

I am naive to Mysql world....:)i was trying to query from the tables using joins,

where i encountered  a problem with the result set...and the table structure are as

below...

```
VIDEO_XXXXX

| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
| VIDEO_ID      | int(255)         
| TAG_NAME      | varchar(1000)
| SHOP_ID       | varchar(100)   FK
| LOVES          | int(255)      
| VIDEO_URL     | varchar(1000) 
| UPLOADED_DATE | 


PLACE_TABLE...

 SHOP_ID       | varchar(100) PK
```

The Query Looks like..

```
   SELECT V.SHOP_ID
     FROM VIDEO_xxxx V  
     JOIN STUB_xxxx_TABLE S  ON S.SHOP_ID=V.SHOP_ID
    WHERE S.COUPON_STATUS='REDEEMED' 
 GROUP BY V.SHOP_ID 
 ORDER BY COUNT(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID) DESC;
```

The result set as follows...

```
+-----------+
| SHOP_ID   |
+-----------+
| 001       |
| 004       |
| 005       |
| 003       |
| 002       |
```

The second query is....

```
   SELECT V.SHOP_ID
     FROM SECOND_TABLE V  
     JOIN STUB_xxxx_TABLE S  ON S.SHOP_ID=V.SHOP_ID  
    WHERE S.COUPON_STATUS='REDEEMED'
 GROUP BY V.SHOP_ID 
 ORDER BY COUNT(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID) DESC;
```

And the result set is...

```
+--------+
| SHOP_ID|
+--------+
|001     |
|004     |
|003     |
|002     |
 005     |
```

I wonder why the order of shop_id shuffles....:( :( any help will be appreciated...:),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the expression `COUNT(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID)` to the where clause:

```
   SELECT V.SHOP_ID,COUNT(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID)
     FROM SECOND_TABLE V  
     JOIN STUB_xxxx_TABLE S  ON S.SHOP_ID=V.SHOP_ID  
    WHERE S.COUPON_STATUS='REDEEMED'
 GROUP BY V.SHOP_ID 
 ORDER BY COUNT(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID) DESC;
```

If you don't want this extra value in the results, you could use a subquery:

```
 SELECT SHOP_ID
   FROM (
          SELECT V.SHOP_ID,COUNT(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID) AS CNT
            FROM SECOND_TABLE V  
            JOIN STUB_xxxx_TABLE S  ON S.SHOP_ID=V.SHOP_ID  
           WHERE S.COUPON_STATUS='REDEEMED'
        GROUP BY V.SHOP_ID 
        )
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

Comment: even if i choose shop_id it returns the different set...:(

Comment: I see that you are selecting from different tables... are `VIDEO_xxxx` and `SECOND_TABLE` the same table?

Comment: No they are different one :(is that because of structure...??

Comment: Try to change the `SELECT` clause for: `SELECT V.SHOP_ID, Count(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID)` just to be sure that ordering is what you're expecting....

Comment: Oh oh if i am putting Count(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID) in queries it returns Expected results thanks for the help....but i dont need Count(S.COUPON_GENERATED_ID) in result set...:(wht can i do...??

Comment: Edited answer to fit your needs